# Are there any issues with using nested functions with eventlisteners?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I just discovered nested functions in AS3 (yeah, late to the party) and am using them in a Flex project. I've always disliked having to use separate functions for essentially modal operations with eventListeners– adds clutter to code and separates operation logic, as well as not being able to easily reference local variables.

The example below for a user selecting a directory seems to work very well and is nice an compact but I am wondering if there are any issues I am not aware of with this approach. Also, with a non-modal operation (e.g. asynchronous like using a `Loader`), is it possible to use nested functions?

```
        private var rootDirectory:File;

        protected function rootBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var tmp:File = File.desktopDirectory;
            tmp.browseForDirectory("Set Project Folder");
            tmp.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onUserSelect);
            tmp.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onUserCancel);

            function onUserSelect(event:Event):void
            {
                tmp.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onUserSelect);
                tmp.removeEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onUserCancel);
                rootDirectory = event.target as File;
            }

            function onUserCancel(event:Event):void
            {
                tmp.removeEventListener(Event.SELECT, onUserSelect);
                tmp.removeEventListener(Event.CANCEL, onUserCancel);
                trace("user canceled");
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you are aware of the scope of the function, and make sure you're not creating memory leaks it's just fine.   You can use them on Loader, but usually the only thing keeping it from being garbage collected is the listener itself, so you can't use weak listeners and you absolutely need to make sure you remove the listener in you closure or it will stay in memory forever.   Most people stay away from them in AS3 (and I generally recommend that to people) because it's easy to create memory leaks or have your closures garbage collected by accident.

Comment: @LDMS – thanks! that is great detail about not using weak refs due to GC - and makes complete sense. I tried using nested functions with a Loader after posting this and it worked fine though handling all possible events leads to code large enough to be a class in itself – so there is that. But for silly small small things like handling user response, I'm really liking this nested approach (and helps me hate eventListeners less ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be some caveats when using anonymous or nested functions.

The first and most important is garbage collection:

In your example, the only thing keeping your `tmp` object from being garbage collected is the `SELECT` and `CANCEL` listeners themselves.  Since you are not setting the weak flag to true, this shouldn't be a problem, however, if you we're using the weak flag (`tmp.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onUserSelect,false,0,true)`) then there is a decent change the `tmp` object would get garbage collected before the user SELECTS or CANCELS a file.

Also, it's imperative that you remove every listener that you attached in this way.   You are doing that in your `onUserCancel` method, so it should be fine, but if you were not, then you would have a memory leak on your hands as every time your click handler ran,  another instance of `tmp` would be created but it would never get garbage collected because of the listeners attached to it.

So to summarize, most people stay away from anonymous/nested methods in AS3 (and I generally/usually recommend that to people) because it's easy to create memory leaks or have your closures garbage collected by accident.   There also may or not be performance differences, but I have never ran tests in that regard.